# Getting an error after my deployment on vercel

Tags: deployment, vite, vercel

I have been looking around on google and stackoverflow and it seems I am not able to get a clear answer..

There is a deployment error in the building stage on vercel..
Below is my log...

```
 [01:02:45.988] Cloning github.com/SinHope/myportfolion (Branch: main, Commit: be09e5f)
[01:02:46.443] Cloning completed: 455.353ms
[01:02:46.865] Looking up build cache...
[01:02:47.158] Build Cache not found
[01:02:47.194] Running "vercel build"
[01:02:47.699] Vercel CLI 28.4.10-6fa5d8b
[01:02:47.999] Installing dependencies...
[01:03:02.453] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[01:03:03.334] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[01:03:03.347] npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
[01:03:03.367] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[01:03:03.615] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[01:03:03.924] npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
[01:03:04.153] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[01:03:04.218] npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[01:03:04.681] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[01:03:05.871] npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[01:03:06.743] npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[01:03:08.274] npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
[01:03:08.708] npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
[01:03:09.156] npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11: please switch to a stable version
[01:03:09.488] npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
[01:03:09.559] npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
[01:03:11.543] npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
[01:03:12.476] npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
[01:03:12.512] npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
[01:03:12.977] npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
[01:03:13.482] npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
[01:03:14.223] npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
[01:03:14.341] npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
[01:03:16.132] npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
[01:03:23.231] npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
**[01:03:29.509] npm ERR! code 1
[01:03:29.509] npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/core-js-pure
[01:03:29.510] npm ERR! command failed
[01:03:29.510] npm ERR! command sh -c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
[01:03:29.510] npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
[01:03:29.510] npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
[01:03:29.512] 
[01:03:29.512] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[01:03:29.512] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-10-14T17_02_48_321Z-debug-0.log
[01:03:29.574] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[01:03:29.574] Running "npm run build"
[01:03:29.887] 
[01:03:29.888] > myportfolion@0.0.0 build
[01:03:29.888] > vite build
[01:03:29.888] 
[01:03:29.894] sh: vite: command not found
[01:03:29.912] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127**
```

It seems from [01:03:29.509] there are multiple errors...

And it seems coming from my package.json file..

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myportfolion",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.7.0",
    "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "node": "^18.9.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "main": "vite.config.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SinHope/myportfolion.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/SinHope/myportfolion/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SinHope/myportfolion#readme",
  "description": ""
}
```

I just cant seem to debug this after many hours.
Would anyone know what's the problem here?

Comment: You have two obvious problems: a lot of deprecated versions (probably not supported on Vercel build, but that would be a question for the Vercel folks) and `sh: vite: command not found`, which indicates that vite isn't installed in your builder. (What you need to do to get vite installed, I don't know, but presumably that's covered in the Vite documentation.)

Comment: Gotten this error in SvelteKit project and landed here via Google search - specific issue in kit - https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8530 (January 2023 issue with adapters)